# How to create a scroll menu in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new in jQuery. Please help me figure out why my menu doesn't work.
I have two issues:

1. In the mobile version, when I click on the link I have to scroll to the anchor and menu is closed. But then I can't open the menu one more time if I want to move to another section. I click on the toggle button and nothing happens. How do I open the mobile menu again after the click?
2. I have to scroll on the website in the menu. This scroll works on codepen, but it doesn't work on the website. There is the same code... Why scroll doesn't work on the website and works on codepen?

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/a007mr/pen/bOvMEP).
Here is the [website](https://a007mr.github.io).

Please help me to figure out where is the bug.

```
$('.burger_active').hide();

$('#burg').on('click', function(){
$('.burger_active').slideToggle();
})

$('.burger_item a').click(function(){
$('.burger_links').slideUp(400);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is ready header with scss styles for burger menu...just add bootstrap, all works perfect, i am using this code in my every project, you just need a little customize it for your project.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom-class">
<div class="logo-mobile">
    <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
</div>
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed burger-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#header_id">
    <div class="burger-wrapper">
        <span class="burger-span"></span>
        <span class="burger-span"></span>
        <span class="burger-span"></span>
    </div>
</button>
<div class="header-wrapper collapse navbar-collapse" id="header_id">
    <div class="main-container">
        <!-- YOUR HEADER CONTENT HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS Styles for it

```
.navbar-custom-class {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1020 !important;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  .logo-mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .header-wrapper {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .burger-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .navbar-custom-class{
    padding: 0 !important;
    .collapsed{
      .burger-span{
        position: static !important;
        &:nth-child(1){
          transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
          transition: all .2s linear !important;
        }
        &:nth-child(3){
          transform: rotate(0deg) !important;
          transition: all .2s linear !important;
        }
        &:nth-child(2){
          width: 25px !important;
          transition: all .2s linear !important;
          margin: 0 auto 5px !important;
        }
      }
    }
    .burger-button{
      display: block !important;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 15px 0 auto;
      border: none;
      height: 50px;
      .burger-wrapper{
        position: relative;
        width: 25px;
        .burger-span{
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          height: 3px;
          width: 25px;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
          background-color: #a5a57d;
          display: block;
          &:nth-child(1){
            transform: rotate(135deg);
            transition: all .2s linear;
          }
          &:nth-child(3){
            transform: rotate(-135deg);
            transition: all .2s linear;
          }
          &:nth-child(2){
            width: 0;
            margin: 0 auto 5px;
          }
          &:last-child{
            margin-bottom: 0;
          }
        }
      }
      &:focus{
        outline: none;
      }
    }
    .logo-mobile{
      display: block;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}
```

Then add anchors with Jquery

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("SELECTOR").on("click", function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("SELECTOR").offset().top - 30
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```